# SQL Query to join the same table based on condition

Tags: sql-server, join

Can anyone please help me write a query to get the below results.

Table goes like this:

```
    Table1
    ------------
    Col1    Col2
    ===     ====
    A       Error
    B       Success
    C       Success
    D       Success
```

This is the result of the query (after using `Join` statement):

```
     Success    Error
     --------   ------
     B          A
     C          A
     D          A
```

Expected result:

```
     Success    Error
     B          A
     C          0
     D          0
```

The values in `Col2` can vary - like mentioned below.

```
    Col1    Col2
    ----    -----
    A       Error
    B       Success
    C       Success
    D       Failed
    E       Unknown
    F       Success
    G       Error
```

And the expected result:

```
    Success Failed  Error   Unknown
    ------- ------  -----   -------
    B       D       A       E   
    C       0       G       0
    F       0       0       0
```

I'm trying to get the values in 2nd column as headers in the new table and the values in 1st column as row values in the new table.

Here is my SQL code:

```
Select tb1.Col1 as Success, tb2.Col1 as Error 
from ( Select * from table1 where Col2 = 'Success') tb1 
Join ( Select * from table1 where Col2 = 'Error') tb2 
on tb1.Col1 is not NUll
```

Comment: Can you please display the SQL you have so far.

Comment: I'm fairly new to SQL queries. I wrote a simple query. Tried to search for possible options online though I did not find any.

<Code>
Select tb1.Col1 as Success, tb2.Col1 as Error from
(
 Select * from table1 where Col2 = 'Success') tb1 
Join
(
 Select * from table1 where Col2 = 'Error') tb2
on tb1.Col1 is not NUll 
</Code>

Comment: Still it is not very clear what are you trying to achieve.... I guess you have problems with your data model design.

Comment: @Anoop You want something unreasonable. The values across a singe table row (or query result row) are meant to refer to *the same thing*. You seem to want multiple independent lists that have nothing to do with each other. (It certainly is possible to write such SQL, it just doesn't make any sense and therefore you shouldn't do it. Maybe you first describe what end result you want to achieve instead.)

Comment: @tomalak yea even i thought so for a while. I thought re-arranging the values to a new table would be easy for later use.. I'm using this query for further processing. Running the query multiple times seem to affect the performance and then i thought of this option.

Comment: "I thought it would be easy for later use" is not a reason, it explains nothing. And I can guarantee, it *won't* be easier to use later. This whole idea goes against the very principles of relational databases and I can only advise you not to pursue it. (That being said: Have you actually *measured* any performance characteristics and compared different approaches? Chances are that fixing your database design will provide more performance benefits than what you are trying here.)

Comment: @Tomalak All i was trying to do is instead of writing 4 separate queries like select col1 from table1 where col2 = 'Success'
select col1 from table1 where col2 = 'Failed'
select col1 from table1 where col2 = 'Error'
select col1 from table1 where col2 = 'Unknown'
and to run them at separate times, I thought I will have them all run at a time and thought it would be easier. If you think this is against the principles of relational database, please excuse me. As I said before, I'm not very familiar with SQL and was wondering if this is possible at all.

Comment: I get that, but relational databases are *geared towards query performance*. Shooting a couple of simple SELECT queries at them is hardly something that needs to be optimized away. Especially not prematurely, and that's what you are doing here: Premature optimization. Leave your table the way it is, two columns, and write the queries you need against it. If you need four queries, so what? If things get slow at some point and you've positively determined those queries as the cause, *then* come back for optimization tips.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to get the list of the items next to each other without any actual relation between them? Something like this with row_number should work:

```
select
  max(case when col2 = 'Success' then col1 else null end) as Success,
  max(case when col2 = 'Failed' then col1 else null end) as Failed,
  max(case when col2 = 'Error' then col1 else null end) as Error,
  max(case when col2 = 'Unknown' then col1 else null end) as Unknown
from (
select
  col2,
  col1,
  row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col1) as rn
from
  data
) TMP
group by RN
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c641/4

Comment: This only works if Success,Failed,Error, and Unknown are the only possible values. If there could be others you need to use COALESCE and dynamic SQL to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think `@JamesZ`'s answer is correct, But if OP needs that result with a dynamic values for `Col2` I suggest this code:

```
Declare @query nvarchar(max) = ''

select @query = @query + ', isnull(max(case when col2 = ''' + Col2 + ''' then col1 else null end), 0) as ' + Col2
from (select distinct Col2 from temptable) dt

set @query = 'select ' + substring(@query, 2, len(@query)) +
   ' from (select col2, col1, row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col1) as rn from temptable) TMP group by RN'

exec(@query)
```

The columns of result now is pending to variety of `Col2`:

```
Error | Failed | Success | Unknown
------+--------+---------+-------------
A     | D      | B       | E
G     | 0      | C       | 0
0     | 0      | F       | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is standart pivot task:

```
Create table t(code char(1), status nvarchar(10))

Insert into t values
( 'A',       'Error'),
(  'B',       'Success'),
(  'C',       'Success'),
(  'D',       'Failed'),
( 'E',       'Unknown'),
(   'F',       'Success'),
( 'G',       'Error')

;with cte as (Select *, row_number() over(partition by status order by code) c from t)
 Select success, failed, error, unknown from cte
 Pivot(max(code) for status in([error],[failed],[unknown],[success])) p
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06e8c/12